# Batch file which deletes a file which last modification was not today

Tags: batch-file, text-files, delete-file

I just want to know:

How can I delete 'log.txt' if the last modification was not today?

With a batch file.

I'm just talking here about 1 FILE!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`forfiles`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753551.aspx):

```
forfiles /D -1 /M log.txt /C "cmd /c del @file"
```

Comment: If I'm going to go through the trouble of installing a new program, I'll install PowerShell instead.

(Also, you should link to forfiles)

Comment: Huh? Forfiles is contained in recent versions of Windows. No need to install anything.

Comment: forfiles is fine, because if you use PowerShell, you really have to install a new program. with forfiles, you can just put forfiles.exe in the directory of the batch.

Answer (score 2):

PowerShell must replace batch.

```
if ((dir log.txt).LastWriteTime -lt [datetime]::today) { del log.txt }
```

Comment: After seeing your example, I agree :)

Comment: ...although I`m a little saddened - I just realized batch was my first language about 25 years ago. GOTOs and everything!

Comment: is it really not possible without powershell?

Not all computers have Powershell. It's going to be something with more users and i don't want to make it too diffecult for them.

Comment: After a career of extreme CMD scripting (self-modifying, multi-threaded, auto-updating, deeply recursive = extreme), I am now convinced that even if it's *possible* in CMD, I want to do it in PowerShell anyway.

Yes, getting PowerShell deployed to pre-Win7 computers is work, and that can suck. But it's so worth it.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't do this in a robust and general way (*).

Powershell, Cygwin, Unix Tools are perfectly good solutions if you can be sure they'll be installed on the target machine.

I wrote a little utility program that takes a path with wildcards and number of days and deletes all files matching the path that are older than the specified number of days.  In my environment this was more convenient than installing a 3rd party package.

(*) 
The following will work for your specific case (modification date not today) as long as the short date format in your regional settings includes the century (i.e. is 10 characters long).  But it doesn't generalize for N days, and I don't like relying on the computer's regional settings for this kind of thing:

```
for %%i in (log.txt) do SET FILETIME=%%~ti
IF NOT "%FILETIME:~0,10%" == "%DATE%" DEL /f log.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Batch makes something that simple very complicated.
If you can use Cygwin, or install Unix Tools, consider doing something like this:

```
find log.txt -mtime +1 -exec rm {} \;
```

**UPDATE**
Found something that might be [useful](http://www.computing.net/answers/programming/batch-file-deleting-files-by-date/13717.html) to you using pure batch. You should be able to modify that and adapt it to suit your needs.

Comment: "Found something that might be useful to you using pure batch" - I wouldn't use it as it relies on assumptions about the regional settings (US date format).

Answer (score 0):

For what its worth, you could use either jscript or vbscript.  Both of these scripting languages have been installed on MS platforms since the mid 90's